# Add new column in asp gridview contains count details of any number of duplicates row of a single row type?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

**I'm having**

I have a asp grid in this gridview there are lot of duplicate rows these rows have different balance details but id is same.

**What i Want**

I want to show only a single row for same id with total balance details,

which will add two column

1. first Column have rows count
2. second have addition of all balance details..

Query is:

```
    string qstr = "Select  id, WalletType, sno, TransferBy, TransferTo, Credit, debit, 
     Balance, vdate, Description, Descid from view_transactionsummary_dealer where vdate               between '" +  objdl.GetDBDate(Session["fromdate"].ToString().Replace("'", "''")) + "' and '" +
 objdl.GetDBDate(Session["todate"].ToString().Replace("'", "''")) + "'" and TransferBy = "Viewstate["TransferBy"]";
```

Comment: paste aspx and .cs code here

Answer (score 0):

if Your want to show only a single row for same id with total balance details
then You have To use `group by id` and `SUM(total balance)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string qstr = " SELECT id, WalletType, sno, TransferBy, TransferTo,Credit, debit, 
                SUM(Balance) Over(Partitiob by id order by (select NULL)), 
                Count(Balance) Over(Partitiob by id order by (select NULL)),vdate,                     
                Description, Descid 
                FROM view_transactionsummary_dealer 
                WHERE vdate Between
                '" +  objdl.GetDBDate(Session["fromdate"].ToString().Replace("'", "''")) 
                + "' AND '" +
                objdl.GetDBDate(Session["todate"].ToString().Replace("'", "''")) 
                + "'" AND 
                TransferBy = "Viewstate["TransferBy"] Group By id,WalletType,sno,TransferBy,TransferTo,Credit, debit,vdate,Description, Descid ";
```